# Android - Change Live Wallpaper configuration while in Live Wallpaper Picker

Tags: android, configuration, live, wallpaper, picker

I'm having some FC in Live Wallpaper Picker because it sounds like the framerate of my Live Wallpaper (40fps) causes FC due to a buffer issue.

Is it possible to change Live Wallpaper configuration while loaded in Live Wallpaper Picker?

This way I'll set the framerate to 10fps (with 10fps there's no issue).

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if you are still rendering the LW while he configuration activity is open, try to pause it using the onPause call and resume rendering on onResume. Seams to me like the configuration activity tries to reload the LW while you are rendering or locking the surface.